# How to perform this async loop without recursion?

Tags: node.js, recursion, leveldb

I wrote a function in NodeJS that puts an array of strings in a levelDB database (each string is the key, and its value becomes the string concatenated to itself or to the value that was already in the database):

```
function addToDB(keys, callback) {
    var added = 0;
    keys.forEach(function(k) {
        db.get(k, function(err, val) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.notFound) {
                    // Insert it into the database
                    db.put(k, k + k, function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        added += 1;
                        if (added == keys.length) {
                            return callback();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                // Update the database
                var newVal = val + k;
                db.put(k, newVal, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    added += 1;
                    if (added == keys.length) {
                        return callback();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

So when I call addToDB with keys = ["a, "b", "c"] and an empty database, the LevelDB ends up with the following key-value pairs (as it should):

```
"a" => "aa"
"b" => "bb"
"c" => "cc"
```

However, I would like to call addToDB multiple times on separate arrays of keys, one after the other. To do that, I have the following code:

```
var key1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
var key2 = ["f", "g", "a"];
var key3 = ["b", "z", "m"];
var keysArray = [key1, key2, key3];

function main(i) {
    var keys = keysArray[i];
    addToDB(keys, function() {
        if (i < keysArray.length - 1) {
            main(i + 1);
        }
    });
}

// Call the main function: 
main(0);
```

After running the above code, which works as it should, the LevelDB database shows:

```
"a" => "aaa"
"b" => "bbb"
"c" => "cc"
"f" => "ff"
"g" => "gg"
"m" => "mm"
"z" => "zz"
```

My question is: is there any way to insert multiple arrays of keys into the database as I've done above (with the precondition that each array of keys has no duplicates) without using a recursive main() function?

Comment: Why not call itself?  Do you realize that if `addToDb()` is async, then there's no stack buildup with the recursive call?

Comment: I didn't realize that - can you explain why there would be no stack buildup in a bit more detail? If there's no risk of stackoverflow, then I don't really mind using this method.

Comment: An async call doesn't call its callback until the previous thread of JS has finished, the stack has completely unwound and then the next event can be pulled from the event queue.  Because of the way node.js is event driven, all async callbacks happen on a future tick with a clean stack so what looks like a recursive call does not have any stack buildup.

Comment: FYI, your error handling where you do `throw err` from an async callback likely won't do anything useful.  You have to find a way to call some callback to communicate back an error.

Comment: Could I just do: `return callback(err)` instead of `throw err`?

Comment: It's not quite that easy when you're in the middle of a `.forEach()` because that won't actually exit the main function and stop things.